# Import a class into the urls.py in Django

Tags: python, django, cx-oracle

In the last few weeks I've switched from developing an application that processes a simple XML file, then writes its contents to an Oracle DB (`cx_Oracle`) and outputs in HTML, to using a Django framework. The Django framework switch wasn't necessary, but since I have an opportunity to develop something by using Django, I thought why not as it is a new area for me and can't damage my CV.

Anyway, I'm having issues with knowing what to write in my urls.py file when importing a Class from the `views.py` file. Here are the current contents:

**urls.py**

```
from myproj.views import Pymat_program

pymatProgram = Pymat_program()

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^pymat/$', pymatProgram.abc),
)
```

**views.py**

```
class Pymat_program:
    def abc(self, request):
        test = "<html><body>Random text.</body></html>"

        return HttpResponse(test)
```

I've tried various permutations of using request, not using request, and also how the class is called in the url tuple, all to no avail. When I use a definition outside of the class (i.e. not in any class), then this is correctly displayed in HTML.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what error does this give?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to wrap your program in a class. (In general, in Python you should treat modules like, say, Java might treat classes with static members only.)

There are two approaches, really:

### Function-based views

#### urls.py

```
from myproj.views import abc_view

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^pymat/$', abc_view),
)
```

#### views.py

```
def abc_view(request):
    test = "<html><body>Random text.</body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(test)
```

### Class-based views

#### urls.py

```
from myproj.views import AbcView

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^pymat/$', AbcView.as_view()),
)
```

#### views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View

class AbcView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        test = "<html><body>Random text.</body></html>"
        return HttpResponse(test)
```

Comment: Super, that worked! I used the class-based view, because I want to perform some other stuff which is better to split into individual methods within the same class. The function view worked, but was limited for my task.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using class based views in Django, so you have to call this class in URL like:

```
from myproj.views import Pymat_program

pymatProgram = Pymat_program()

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^pymat/$', pymatProgram.as_view()),
)
```

and then use get or post methods name in class like:

```
class Pymat_program:
    model = ModelName

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
```

2nd way is to use function based views:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.view_name),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def view_name(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

for more details look into [class based views docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/)